# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split_contents'

Tags: django, django-advanced-filters

I'm trying to use **django-advanced-filters**.

```
Python 3.8.10 

Django==3.2

django-advanced-filters==2.0.0

sqlparse==0.4.3
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'advanced_filters',

    'semantics',
    'sites',

]
```

**Urlpatterns**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^advanced_filters/', include('advanced_filters.urls')), 
]
```

**Admin**

```
class SemanticsClusterAdmin(AdminAdvancedFiltersMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ("page",)
    list_display = ["id", "detail_view", "page", "name", ]

    advanced_filter_fields = (
        'id',
        'page',
    )


    exclude = []


admin.site.register(SemanticsClusters, SemanticsClusterAdmin)
```

**Traceback**

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/marketing3/marketing3/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^advanced_filters/', include('advanced_filters.urls')), 
  File "/home/michael/Documents/PyCharmProjects/marketing3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 1369, in url
    bits = token.split_contents()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split_contents'
```

Documentation: https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters/blob/develop/README.rst

Why does it blow up? And how can I cope with the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studying the documentation for [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/) and the [Readme](https://github.com/modlinltd/django-advanced-filters) for Django Advance Filters. It looks like there is a typo or deprecated use of "url" in the Readme for Advance Filters

Instead of

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^advanced_filters/', include('advanced_filters.urls')), 
]
```

Use:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^advanced_filters/', include('advanced_filters.urls')), 
]
```